# Unit Test For Functional Component React

Tags: reactjs

I would like to write a simple unit test for one functional `React` component. I have search on the internet but it looks like most of those unit test is for class component. The component is just a simple `form` with one `input` and one `submit`. I think I need to write two tests one for `input` field and the other for `submit` button.
Component is:

```
import React from 'react';


function Bar(props) {
 return (
  <form
  className="form-wrapper"      
  onSubmit={event => props.onSubmit(event)}
 >
  <input
    placeholder="Add new todo"
    value={props.newTodoName}
    onChange={event => props.onInputChange(event)}
  />
  <button className="btn custom-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
 );
}

export default Bar;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is extract any callback functions out of the component and write them out such that they accept their scope dependencies explicitly.

Indicative only:

```
import React from 'react';

const actions = {
  onSubmit: ([onSubmit]) => event => onSubmit(event),
  onInputChange: ([onInputChange]) => event => onInputChange(event),
};

function Bar(props) {
 return (
  <form
  className="form-wrapper"
  onSubmit={actions.onSubmit([props.onSubmit])}
 >
  <input
    placeholder="Add new todo"
    value={props.newTodoName}
    onChange={actions.onInputChange([props.onInputChange])}
  />
  <button className="btn custom-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
 );
}

export default Bar;
```

Now everything is pure and easily testable.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Bar, { actions } from './Bar';

describe('Bar', () => {
  it('should render a button', () => {
    render(<Bar />)
    expect(screen.getByRole('button')).toHaveTextContent('Submit');
  });

  describe('onSubmit', () => {
    it('should call onSubmit', () => {
      const onSubmit = jest.fn();
      const action = actions.onSubmit([onSubmit]);
      const event = 'test-event';
      action(event)
      expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(event);
    });
  });

  describe('onInputChange', () => {
    it('should call onInputChange', () => {
      const onInputChange = jest.fn();
      const action = actions.onInputChange([onInputChange]);
      const event = 'test-event';
      action(event)
      expect(onInputChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(event);
    });
  });
});
```

This is not 100% idiomatic React code, but it's close. If there's a lot going on in your callbacks, I think it makes sense to separate them out into their own functions and to test them independently.

Note, I have my action functions accept their dependencies as an array to make it easier to graduate to `useCallback`. Again, not idiomatic, I think the hook linter doesn't like it, but so clean!

```
const deps = [props.onSubmit];
const onSubmit = useCallback(actions.onSubmit(deps), deps);
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference between testing Class component and Functional component.

Read through the docs of your testing framework carefully.

Comment: could you please write those two tests for this form ?

Comment: Post your current code so that I can look at what you tried so far, then I can help you.

Comment: I made a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bohr-8mhv9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: could you check out the sandbox ?

Comment: yes there are. the biggest is that you can hardly and only partially make unit tests or integration tests with functional components. when switching from class components to functional components, you've got to dump your unit tests and integration tests. You can still do functional tests though.